# how can I reuse the function to update different parts of the state of a React component?

Tags: reactjs

```
class App extends Component {      
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  Foo: [],
  Bar: []
};
this.xfetch('Alice',  this.state.Foo);    
}

xfetch = (param, target)=> {
   const res = getRes(param);//db request async
   //onCompleted: () => { 
   this.setState(({ target}) => {
      const newArr = [...target, res ];

      return {
        target: newArr
      };
    });
}

addBar = input => {
this.xfetch(input,  this.state.Bar);

};
```

the code above doesn't work, and I don't want to write multiple versions of `xfetch()` for different parts of the state

*first part of the state I want to set in the constructor

Comment: You can't `setState` in the constructor. Try using one of the component lifecycle functions instead. Can you provide more detail around usage and expected result(s)?

Comment: @DrewReese [source frome github](https://github.com/johnymontana/spacetime-reviews/blob/master/src/App.js)
Lines 83 & 122 
two different functions are written for two different parts of the state, and I want one that is parameterizable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what it sounds like, you are wanting to update state dynamically?

try this:

```
xfetch = async (param, target) => {
   const res = await getRes(param)
   this.setState({ [target]: [...target, res ] })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, target has to be a string, for example "Foo"

```
xfetch = async (param, target) => {
    const res = await getRes(param)
    this.setState({ [target]: [...this.state[target], res ] })
}

this.xfetch("Alice", "Foo");
```